# Format numeric input in TextBox with bound StringFormat

Tags: data-binding, string-formatting, silverlight-5.0

So, although the title sounds like so many other similar questions (like those that come up under the "Questions with similar titles" box), I feel like this is a unique circumstance.  What I'm trying to accomplish is this:  I have an object that has 2 properties on it.  the first is a decimal value, and the second is a string property that stores the .Net format type (p/g/n/etc.)..

What I'd ultimately like to do is something like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=decimalproperty, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={Binding path=formatproperty}}" />
```

Has anyone ever done anything like this?  I thought of trying to use a ValueConverter, but since you'd have to bind to the full object to access to both the decimalproperty and the formatproperty, the convertback doesn't seem like it would work.  Any advice or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up making a viewmodel over the object model, and handled the formatting there, along with changing my UI to use a DataGrid in Silverlight.  I then built a templated column and built 2-3 controls to handle the data appropriately.  Not satisfied with the way it was implemented, but it achieved what I wanted to achieve for the client.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using like a Unique Data Type ?  I think, its better to convert the Object to String

```
Stirng MyResult=(MyCoomonObject.ToString()) ;
```